# Comparing number of average case and worst case swaps in selection sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I came across following problem:

> State true or false:
> In selection sort, total swaps in average case >= total swaps in worst case

After pondering a bit and trying out some examples, I reached following conclusions:

> In selection sort, worst case = best case = avg case = O(n^2).
>
> In selection sort, time complexity is determined by number of comparisons which is always n(n-1)/2 = O(n^2)
>
> So we cannot say, total swaps in average case>=total swaps in worst case.
> On the other hand, minimum number of swaps happen when array is already sorted. And maximum number of swaps happen when first half of the array contains n/2 largest elements in reverse sorted order and second half of the array contains n/2 smallest elements in sorted order. However this will not necessarily always lead to n-1 swaps. Instead it might lead to n-1, n-2 or even n-3 swaps as explained in the figure below:
> [image]

I am correct with above thinking?

Comment: The number of comparisons is completely irrelevant for this analysis.

Comment: When problem says "total swaps in average case >= worst case". I was interpreting total swaps in avg case "of overall sorting time"  >= worst case "of overall sorting time". Overall sorting time in selection sort depends on number of comparisons = n(n-1)/2 = O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

An average case cannot exceed the worst case, this is impossible.

The average case can equal the worst case, provided all cases have the same complexity.

Depending on how exactly you implement SelectionSort, you have two situations:

- if you "blindly" swap after every selection, the count of swaps is N-1 and is constant;
- if you swap only when the selected element is not already in place, the count of swaps can be less (in the best case - a sorted array - the count is 0).

Comment: average case "of selection sort" does not necessarily correspond to average case "of number of swaps", especially when there are other factors dominating overall execution time. Here such factor is number of comparisons as there are always O(n^2) comparisons against O(n) swaps. Thus time complexity of selection sort depends on comparisons, not swaps.

Comment: @anir: the question is about the number of swaps. Both the number of comparisons and the global time complexity are irrelevant.

Comment: When question said xyz case, I thought it was talking about overall run time complexity as its trivially obvious that best case xyz <= avg case xyz <= worst case xyz. So I though it was talking about swaps in avg case overall time vs worst case overall time, instead of swaps in avg case swaps vs worst case swap. Anyway, if we assume my interpretation, then my conclusion is correct?

Comment: @anir: I don't adhere to your interpretation.